# Trickery to put page in special mode

Tags: javascript, html

I am still a noob on web app development. I have a vision of putting my app in a mode where clicking on fields does not activate their normal behavior but instead some special behavior. For instance clicking on a button instead of submitting a form toggles it enabled/disabled so that I can record this state in a database for a specific role's access or not to a feature behind this button. Another mode would be translate mode where clicking on the button pops up a div where it is possible to translate its text to another language so I can record this in a translation table.

In other words, if you login as an administrator there will be functions available to you e.g. Translate or Access Control (+selecting a role from a list of roles) and when you select any of these two categories, it puts the entire site into the correct mode allowing you to translate in-line or enable disable items.

I am using plain HTML and JavaScript but in an Angular setting. I'd prefer to leave angular out of it.

Is there a pattern for doing this kind of thing ?

Comment: You can use a global variable, that you can toggle to trigger special mode or not. How about https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Lhr6cemn/

Comment: I was more hoping for a generalized mechanism through something such as introspection. I used button as an example but should for instance be possible to translate a label as well or deactivate an input field.

Comment: You could still use Mr Lister's method. You just have to perform that "mode check" in every click function you write.